# How to get all data which time is in range to next 2 hours from current time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `tblSMS` with a `datetime` and `time` column (and some other columns).

I get all reminder within next 2 hours on dashboard so I want to get data from table where `datetime` is today and `time` is within the next 2 hours.

I used this stored procedure, but it is not working:

```
select * 
from tblSMS 
where  
    SMSTime >= (SELECT Convert(varchar(5), GetDate(), 108)) 
    and (SMSTime <= (SELECT Convert(varchar(5), (Select dateadd (hour, 2, getdate())), 108)))
    and Convert(varchar(10), SMSDate, 110) = Convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 110)
```

Thanks

Comment: Show some samples. Are the values in `time` column same as in `datetime` column?

Comment: What is the data format of the SMSTime and SMSDate columns, and what are some example data stored in them?

Comment: Never convert date/time information into text and then use comparison operators such as greater than. This causes "implicit type conversions" and these slow down queries.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `time` column if you are storing in proper `datetime` format. It's better to make comparisons in `datetime` format. Otherwise you may have troubles if next 2 hours falls on the next day.

```
select * 
from tblSMS 
where  
    SMSDate between getdate() and dateadd(hh, 2, getdate())
```

Combine two columns to get datetime if you are storing `SMSDate` as a date

```
select * 
from tblSMS 
where  
    SMSDate + cast(SMSTime as datetime) between getdate() and dateadd(hh, 2, getdate())
```

Comment: This answer is sound but `datetime` isn't a "format", it is a level of precision. Thinking of temporal data as formats leads to all sorts of confusion and we get to see this as an example in the original query which converts date/times into strings. Date/datetime/datetime2/time information is stored as sets of numbers in the database.